# Rails Routing except action in namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to exclude an action(s) from all resources in a namespace?

For example, if I have

```
namespace :api
  resources posts, :except: [:new]
  resources comments, :except: [:new]
  resources tags, :except: [:new]
```

I'd rather just define this behavior once.

Answer (score 0):

Adding :except to the namespace seems to work:

```
namespace :api, :except: [:new]
  resources posts
  resources comments
  resources tags
```